# GCC Command-Line Argument Pickiness

Tags: gcc, command-line, g++, command-line-arguments

GCC can get pretty picky about the order in which it accepts its arguments:

```
# Works.
g++ Foo.cpp -L. -I. -lBar -o Foo

# Linker errors.
g++ -o Foo -I. -L. -lBar Foo.cpp
```

What, specifically, are the ordering requirements for command-line options?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Libraries are loaded on demand based on the symbols required from them, so the library which provides a symbol needed by something else must follow that something else.  This is historical; arguably a modern system should resolve symbols automatically, handling loops sensibly (that being the reason for the rule; you broke dependency cycles manually by specifying libraries in order and as many times as needed), but `g++` follows the traditional rule so it will work with vendor `ld`s.  (GNU `ld` doesn't work everywhere, so it wouldn't be possible to rely on it to resolve symbol dependency loops.  There are also bootstrapping concerns even on platforms where GNU `ld` does work.)  Similarly, other linker-oriented options must be specified in the correct order relative to the things they affect (for example, a `-L` option must precede a library which lives in the specified directory; this can be important if a library in one directory shadows a library of the same name in a standard directory).

Comment: Bootstrapping concerns?  Like what?

Comment: If `gcc`/`g++` depended on a behavior specific to GNU `ld`, you get into complications as to what needs to be built in what order to get the GNU toolchain running. `gcc`/`g++` goes to great lengths to build with standard vendor tools for bootstrapping purposes, since many GNU programs rely on `gcc` extensions, and depending on a GNU `ld`-specific behavior would break this.